# Deriving the superposition principle of forces from momentum

Tags: momentum

so I've nicely derived the fact that $\textbf{p}_{tot} = \sum_{i=1}^N \textbf{p}_i=\sum_{i=1}^N m_i\textbf{v}_i=const$

I think I also derived nicely the idea of a force and the relationship: $\frac{d\textbf{p}}{dt}=\textbf{F}$

Now, can i do this:

We know that $\textbf{p}_{tot} = \sum_{i=1}^N \textbf{p}_i$ and $\frac{d\textbf{p}}{dt}=\textbf{F}$.

I'd like to derive the superposition principle of forces from the conversation of impluses - if that's possible.

We take the derivative of the former:

$\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{p}_{tot} = \frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i=1}^N \textbf{p}_i = \sum_{i=1}^N m_i \ddot{\textbf{x}}=\sum_{i=1}^N \textbf{F}_i=const$

So that looks okay mathematically but what I'm missing is the fact, that the forces all must work on the same point of mass - which I can't read out of the math here. Can someone tell me how I could argue here to get that idea out of it?

Like, how would I now argue that all $\textbf{F}_i$ are working on the same point of mass?

Assuming now we did have a nice argument for the above, then we can further say: if $\sum_{i=1}^N \textbf{F}_i=0 \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\textbf{p}_{tot}=0$ thus we don't have a change in motion. Or said differently: If all forces cancel themselfes out, we don't see a change of motion.

Question: My question is, as stated earlier, how I can argue nicely that all forces are working on the same point of mass. (It's intuitively clear, but is there a way to get it from the math?)

Comment: But each $F_i$ is acting on a different mass by definition. $F_i$ is the net force acting on each mass $m_i$, so all $F_i$ are not acting on the same point of mass.

Comment: So all you can say now is that if the sum of all net forces cancel out, then the total momentum of the entire system does not change. There can still exist non-zero net forces on each mass.

Comment: Yeah that also concerned me. Can I somehow resolve it?

Comment: What are you trying to get at exactly? Your math is not wrong as it is.

Comment: I want to use the fact that $\dot{\textbf{p}}=\textbf{F}$ and $F_{tot}=\sum_i \textbf{F_i}$ to derive the super position principle of forces. So basically I wanted to mathematically derive the $\Rightarrow$ in the following statement: $\textbf{p}_{tot}=\sum_i \textbf{p}_i=const \Rightarrow \textbf{F}_{tot} = \sum_i \textbf{F}_i=0$. I think that's fine, my physical intepretation was just wrong. What I did here was basically saying: If we have an isolated system with a constant net impuls, the net force on that system is zero.

Comment: I actualyl wanted to derive the fact that if we have a mass m and i forces, then we can just add them up. Like, how do we know we can just add the forces up?

Comment: I don't think you can derive that. It is just something that has been verified to be true.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. Going to research a bit more then :)